# Why do Mosteller & Tukey use 1/6 to start their "flog" (logit) transformation

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, exploratory-data-analysis

Mosteller & Tukey (*Data Analysis and Regression*) recommend transforming counted fractions with the `flog` transformation:
$$
\frac{\log{(n)}}{\log{(m - n)}}.
$$
But when $m = n$ they recommend **starting** the `flog`:
$$
\frac{\log{(n + \frac{1}{6})}}{\log{(m - n + \frac{1}{6})}}.
$$
On p. 93 they call $\frac{1}{6}$ a *standard fraction*, but nowhere have I found a rationale for this value.